# How to allow git pull as a sudo

Tags: ssh, sudo, git

I am using `git pull` (without sudo) every day on my machine, I have one key in ssh folder (`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)

Problem is, that I cant call `sudo git pull`, because I am getting an error:

```
sudo git pull
git@gitlab.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Probably there is problem with my key.

I need to call it in my external script (using sudo).

How can I call `sudo git pull` ? How can I add key for sudo?

In short: `pull` doesnt work with `sudo` why?

Comment: Why are you using sudo to run git?

Comment: There is something wrong with your workflow if you are required to use `sudo` with `git`.

Comment: The author already stated why needs sudo: "I need to call it in my external script (using sudo).". Imagine that a script that requires to run with sudo needs to perform a git operation amongst it's tasks. I think that's the use case for the question.

Answer (score 3):

When you run something with `sudo` without specifying a particular user, you are running it as `root` user.

As it seems you cloned your repository via SSH, `git` (actually SSH I guess) is looking for the SSH private key for the `root` user instead of the one of your user: `/root/.ssh/` vs. `/home/your-user/.ssh/`.

##### You can try the following:

- Run your script using `sudo -E`: The `-E` preserves your user environment variables to be defined when running on sudo (some SSH variables, I think `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and/or `SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER` will be required, but I don't know much about the details).
- Inside your script, run the git command "as the user" instead "as root". To achieve that, you can rely on `sudo` again :)

  ```
  sudo -E -u $(logname) git pull
  ```

Notice that you're using `sudo -E` twice: One to call the script, and another to call `git` inside the script.

That should work :)

P.S. In case you need a finer grained control of which environment variables are exported to sudo, use `--preserve-env=list` option instead of `-E`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use git with sudo it looks for a the key in `/root/.ssh/` and not in `/home/yourusername/.ssh/`. You just have to copy it into the former and it should work.